# PHP pg_fetch_object function returning false

Tags: php, postgresql

Before post this question, i searched a lot in internet but did not find anything that could solve my problem.

```
<?php
   $result=pg_query($this->conn_link,$strSqlQuery) or die(pg_last_error());
   if($result)
      $data=pg_fetch_object($result);
?>
```

So, after execute the code above, the value of `$data` is false, using `var_dump()` function. The strange thing is that if i copy the sql string and execute directly on SGBD (Sql Manager 2007) it returning data correctly!!!

I tried use functions that return last error, but no error was shown. So, i don't have any idea why is this happening. This never happened to me.

So guys, what could be or what i could to do for try to discover this issue. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you use `pg_fetch_array`? I see nothing wrong in your code. did you `var_dump` your `data` right after you fetched it?

Comment: You've tried exactly the same query, same parameters,...?? Cause the doc says only: `FALSE is returned if row exceeds the number of rows in the set, there are no more rows, or on any other error.`

Comment: Sadly, same parameters!

Comment: pg_fetch_array, same result lolka_bolka.

Comment: @noisae The connection you're passing as argument is the right one? Sry for dump question, only want to help... Cause `PostgreSQL database connection resource. When connection is not present, the default connection is used. The default connection is the last connection made by pg_connect() or pg_pconnect().`

Comment: Hi @Robert. Thank you for your reply. Yes, is the right one.

Comment: And what happens when you try a simple `SELECT *` directly passed as text?

Comment: I tried that too. Same result. I downloaded database client and i will run on my pc to try to discover what may be causing this issue. If i can resolve this, i post here the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Be careful when use pg_query without conection parameter, it will pick up the default conection, which maybe can cause wrong conection(other database conection for example) and your query will fail.

For me, i forced a re-conection with bd before execute the query and it worked beautifully.

```
<?php
   $bd->conect();
   $result=pg_query($this->conn_link,$strSqlQuery) or die(pg_last_error());
   if($result)
      $data=pg_fetch_object($result);
?>
```